# Regex: replace text unless url?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this basic Chrome extension that replaces instances of `'hipster'` with `'James Montour'`. However, it searches the whole `body` for these instances, and replaces the word even in URLs, which breaks images and links (obviously). I need to figure out how to prevent that and I'm not good with `regex`.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var replaced = $("body").html().replace(/hipster/gi, 'James Montour');
  $("body").html(replaced);
});
```

What should I try?

Comment: Did you try with adding word boundaries ? `\bhipster\b` .An example would be better..

Answer (score 0):

An exact word would be at the first followed by a space  or at the last preceded by a space or in the middle preceeded and followed by a space. This logic was used in the below regex,

```
string.replace(/(^| )hipster(?= |$)/g, "$1James Montour")
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aO5dB0/7)

**Explanation:**

- `(^| )` captures the line starting anchor or space.
- `hipster(?= |$)` Matches the word hipster only if it's followed by a space or an end of the line  anchor.